# "File not found" error after installing and starting service in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, driver

I try to create my own service to write driver in Windows. But after creating, I cannot start it, because system says "File not found".

`pszDriver = "D:\\OSS\\Debug\\IOtrserv.sys";
hSrv = CreateService ( hMan, "IOtrserv", "IOtrserv", 
   SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER, SERVICE_DEMAND_START,
   SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL, pszDriver, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );`

And after that calling `StartService ( hSrv, 0, NULL );` fails with "File not found error".
If we look at this service before execution of previous line, we will see that binary file of service has name with question marks in the beginning. Sorry for non-english system language.
Please, help, how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: That's what the path looks like from the kernel's point of view.  I don't think that's the problem; Symantec Endpoint Protection installs a number of kernel components, and they look the same.  The problem might be something else, perhaps a missing or improper dependency?  (The first thing to try is to see if it works if it is on the C drive.  I wouldn't be surprised if Windows can only load kernel components from the boot drive.)